# Receiving snmptraps in a C program

Tags: c, net-snmp, snmptrapd

I want to write a C program which receives snmptraps sent from another machine and parses them.
I am able to do this from the  command line, but have no idea on how to implement this in C.

I searched online and found most code was in ruby or the atleast C++ which had a traplistener class.

Is there any way to receive snmptraps from within a C program ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best library is to use [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/). It supports both C and C++ linkages.

Comment: I am  already using the net-snmp headers inside my code to send traps. I am just clueless on how to start a trap listener from inside the code. Can you point me to some sample code  which has snmp trap listener using the net-snmp lib?

Comment: There is not enough documentation. But, here's a reference  link to [snmptrapd](http://fossies.org/linux/net-snmp/apps/snmptrapd.c)